# MongoDB RHEL Failure to startup after cold reboot

Tags: mongodb, rhel

Mongodb failing to start on RHEL.

Here is the output from service restart: any idea?

> 2011-06-17 18:44:06,387
>   [INFO][Dummy-3] initialize() @
>   connection.py:48 - Attempting Database
>   connection with seeds = localhost
>   2011-06-17 18:44:06,389
>   [CRITICAL][Dummy-3] initialize() @
>   connection.py:55 - Database
>   initialization failed

Comment: Wait, is this  from restarting MongoDB itself? If so, then why does it say connection.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best to look at the mongod server logs to find the issue. It is most likely because the lock file was not cleaned up because you had an unclean shutdown.

Comment: that was exactly it. is I did a service mongod status it showed active (exited) b/c it died right after startup b/c the lock file was not deleted.  Unfortunately the service calls eat the STDOUT.